# Drush command using chef causing error "Command needs a higher bootstrap level to run"

Tags: drush

Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'

```
---- Begin output of /usr/local/drush/drush -y en views ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
need invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
The drush command 'en views' could not be executed.                  [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This error often occurs when Drush is trying to bootstrap a
site that has not been installed or does not have a configured
database.
```

Please note that database and executing command lines are having full privileges.

Answer (score 0):

In your drush command you may need to specify the location of your Drupal files. Use `--root=<path>` argument.

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#options

Comment: Tried with this option , but the issue still exists :-(

Comment: Does your drush command work as expected from the terminal? Try it with the same user account as Chef and from the same working directory. This might narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris. As you said, i am able to execute the drush command from my drupal path in the terminal.But when it comes via chef, it is getting failed.

Comment: Try using both `--root=<path>` and `--uri=<mysite.com>` as options to your Drush command in your chef recipe.  That should clear things up.